# C# Extension Properties

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am doing some math - combining, reusing, extending different analyses methods over the same original data set. It would be reasonable to use C# extension methods in my case instead of defining everything in one class. The same time there are too much stuff to be constantly recalculated in this extension methods - I definitely need something like extension write-once/calculated-once extension property mechanism. Here is how it looks like and how to consume it. Please comment on this if anything smells for you (sources are on [GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/libs)).

Let's imagine that we have class `Person`:

```
namespace People
{
    class Person
    {
    }
}
```

To extend it with couple properties:

- `Name` - write-once extension property
- `Salutation` - calculated-once extension property

We define:

```
namespace HumanResource
{
    using People;
    using ExtensionProperties;

    static class ContactInfoProperties
    {
        static readonly ExtensionProperty<string> NameProperty =
            new ExtensionProperty<string>();
        static readonly ExtensionProperty<string> SalutationProperty = 
            new ExtensionProperty<string>();

        public static string Name(this Person person, string name) =>
            person.Add(NameProperty, name);

        public static string Name(this Person person) =>
            person.Get(NameProperty);

        public static string Salutation(this Person person) =>
            person.GetOrAdd(SalutationProperty, () => "Hello " + person.Name());
    }
}
```

where `ExtensionProperty<T>` and three extension methods `Add`, `Get`, `GetOrAdd` are being imported from `ExtensionProperties` namespace.

We define `ExtensionProperty<T>` fields to uniquely identify property identity and type for the storage system.

`Add` method adds property value to the storage. It throws `RedefinedPropertyException` if value has been already associated with the property.

`Get` method tries to read value from the storage or throws `UndefinedPropertyException` if values is missing.

`GetOrAdd` method always succeeds by attempting to return existing value. It calculates, persists and returns new value if missing.

We can use it this way:

```
var person = new Person();
person.Name("John Doe");
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + person.Name());
Console.WriteLine("Salutation: " + person.Salutation());
```

OK, the `ExtensionProperties' lib itself comes below.

`ExtensionProperty<T>` definition:

```
public interface IExtensionProperty
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class ExtensionProperty<T> : IExtensionProperty
{
    public ExtensionProperty([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        Name = name ?? "UnknownProperty";
    }

    public string Name { get; }    
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

`Add`, `Get`, `GetOrAdd` extension methods comes from:

```
public static class ExtensionProperty
{
    static ConditionalWeakTable<object, ValueStore> Table { get; } = 
        new ConditionalWeakTable<object, ValueStore>();

    static ValueStore Store(object context) => 
        Table.GetOrCreateValue(context);

    public static T Add<T>(
        this object context, 
        ExtensionProperty<T> property, 
        T value) =>
        Store(context)
            .Add(property, value);

    public static T Get<T>(
        this object context, 
        ExtensionProperty<T> property) =>
        Store(context)
            .Get(property);

    public static T GetOrAdd<T>(
        this object context, 
        ExtensionProperty<T> property, 
        Func<T> valueFactory) =>
        Store(context)
            .GetOrAdd(property, valueFactory);        
}
```

Where `ValueStore` are:

```
class ValueStore
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> Stores { get; } = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

    ValueStore<T> Store<T>() => 
        (ValueStore<T>)Stores.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), t => new ValueStore<T>());

    public T Add<T>(
        ExtensionProperty<T> property, 
        T value) =>
        Store<T>()
            .Add(property, value);

    public T Get<T>(
        ExtensionProperty<T> property) =>
        Store<T>()
            .Get(property);

    public T GetOrAdd<T>(
        ExtensionProperty<T> property, 
        Func<T> valueFactory) =>
        Store<T>()
            .GetOrAdd(property, valueFactory);             
}
```

and strictly typed `ValueStore<T>` to bypass boxing/unboxing:

```
class ValueStore<T>
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<ExtensionProperty<T>, T> Values { get; } = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<ExtensionProperty<T>, T>();

    public T Add(ExtensionProperty<T> property, T value)
    {
        if(!Values.TryAdd(property, value))
            throw new RedefinedPropertyException(property);

        return value;
    }

    public T Get(ExtensionProperty<T> property)
    {
        T value;
        if(!Values.TryGetValue(property, out value))            
            throw new UndefinedPropertyException(property);

        return value;
    }

    public T GetOrAdd(ExtensionProperty<T> property, Func<T> valueFactory) =>
        Values.GetOrAdd(property, p => valueFactory());        
}
```

Exceptions:

```
public abstract class ExtensionPropertyException : Exception
{
    protected ExtensionPropertyException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class UndefinedPropertyException : ExtensionPropertyException
{
    public UndefinedPropertyException(IExtensionProperty property)
        : base($"Undefined {property.Name}.")
    {
    }
}

public class RedefinedPropertyException : ExtensionPropertyException
{
    public RedefinedPropertyException(IExtensionProperty property)
        : base($"Redefined {property.Name}.")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. API in your example is really confusing, since you use `Name` method to both set and get property value. You should make your intent clear, by using, say, `GetName` and `SetName` for method names.
2. You should probably add `T Value` property to your `ExtensionProperty<T>` class, and use it to store the value, instead of `ConcurrentDictionary`. I think it will make more sense.
3. `IExtensionProperty` interface is awkward. I think you can do just fine without it.
4. Finally, imho, you are not making a convincing case. Why can't you just create a regular class (or classes) to  analyze data and another class (or classes) to store the results? Call me old-fashioned, but the idea of using attached properties to analyze data strikes me as a truly horrifying design decision. At least it is not something I am willing to maintain, debug or review. :)

Comment: 1) It is a jQuery influence where we mimic properties by functions. What about Name()/SetName(value) pair? 2) It is a WPF influence. We can not have Value property on ExtentionProperty<T>:  there are 0..n values per 1 property. 3) IExtensionProperty is used to generate exceptions. 4) It is like WPF attached properties. The same situation, the same solution.

Comment: 1) I would still prefer my version. It is a common naming pattern in .Net and most developers will be used to it. 2) I don't follow. 3) No, you use  IExtensionProperty.Name property, which you can pass to exception constructor directly. 4) Your situation is nothing like we have in WPF. `DependencyProperty` is there to support data binding, PropertyChanged notifications, styles, default values, etc. That is why its obscure syntax and implementation are justified. The situation you described in your question on the other hand is fairly straightforward and can be solved using regular patterns.

Comment: 1) I prefer to do not use Get prefix in domain logic. There is a good explanation in Vernon's [book](http://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577). 2) How many values we have  per instances of WPF DependencyProperty? It is many to one. 3) DRY - I will need to resolve to the name every time constructing exception. Primitive Obsession - PropertyException logically intended to express property problem, not name problem. 4) It is not like DependancyProperty, it is exactly the same thing as AttachedProperty. There are two big differences :)

Comment: 4) The solution is similar, I agree. I argue your point about the problem being the same. Problem of analyzing data and storing results is nothing like building a UI framework. It is a straightforward problem, which you are trying _really hard_ to make complex by using the wrong tool. I had a lot of "fun" debugging interactions between `DependencyProperties`in the past, and in my opinion it is not something other people should look forward to. But oh well, I mean its your code, do what you feel is right. :)

Comment: 3) There is also KISS and YAGNI. But those are clearly not your favorites. :)

Comment: 1) Look, I can put ConditionalWeakTable in a property metadata and expose value access on it instead of object itself view extension api. It just looks totally unreasonable. Property metadata are property metadata, they have different, single, dedicated responsibility. Yes, like WPF `DependencyProperty`. 2) Are you having something against extension methods? They make mechanisms like LINQ possible by the way. I am in the same situation in my domain. This lib just caches the result, this is it. Mix of calculation methods borrowing from each other requires some help in implementing mixins.